# Merging two dataframes with different number & order of columns (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I'm having trouble with merging two dataframes with different columns (some common columns, but the number are different) in pandas. The order of these common columns is not the same. For example:

```
df1
   A B C                                                     
R1 1 2 3
R2 2 1 2
R3 1 1 1

df2
   B C                                                 
R1 2 1
R2 1 1
```

I want the result to be:

```
df1
   A B C                                                     
R1 1 2 3
R2 2 1 2
R3 1 1 1
R4 N 2 1
R5 N 1 1

(N = NULL)
```

There are many columns (>100) so I don't want to manually input the column names. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, update the index of `df2` to be consecutive to the index of `df1`:

```
df2.index = ['R' + str(i + 1) for i in range(len(df1), len(df1) + len(df2))]
```

Now, we can use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to concatenate the two dataframes following the column names:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

Result:

```
      A  B  C
R1  1.0  2  3
R2  2.0  1  2
R3  1.0  1  1
R4  NaN  2  1
R5  NaN  1  1
```